# why do we need delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advantages of using delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302819/advantages-of-using-delegates)

I know this question has been asked before, but I have one doubt-when we can directly call a method, why we should take help of delegates? can somebody explain with a proper example/reason/scenario

EDIT: can somebody explain with a code snippet