# Delegates, Why?

Tags: c#, delegates

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When would you use delegates in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191153/when-would-you-use-delegates-in-c)
>   [The purpose of delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687626/the-purpose-of-delegates)

I have seen many question regarding the use of delegates. I am still not clear where and WHY would you use delegates instead of calling the method directly.

I have heard this phrase many times: "The delegate object can then be passed to code which can call the referenced method, without having to know at compile time which method will be invoked."

I don't understand how that statement is correct.

I've written the following examples. Let's say you have 3 methods with same parameters:

```
   public int add(int x, int y)
    {
        int total;
        return total = x + y;
    }
    public int multiply(int x, int y)
    {
        int total;
        return total = x * y;
    }
    public int subtract(int x, int y)
    {
        int total;
        return total = x - y;
    }
```

Now I declare a delegate:

```
public delegate int Operations(int x, int y);
```

Now I can take it a step further a declare a handler to use this delegate (or your delegate directly)

Call delegate:

```
MyClass f = new MyClass();

Operations p = new Operations(f.multiply);
p.Invoke(5, 5);
```

or call with handler

```
f.OperationsHandler = f.multiply;
//just displaying result to text as an example
textBoxDelegate.Text = f.OperationsHandler.Invoke(5, 5).ToString();
```

In these both cases, I see my "multiply" method being specified. Why do people use the phrase "change functionality at runtime" or the one above?

Why are delegates used if every time I declare a delegate, it needs a method to point to? and if it needs a method to point to, why not just call that method directly? It seems to me that I have to write more code to use delegates than just to use the functions directly.

Can someone please give me a real world situation? I am totally confused.

Comment: +1 - Good question Mage! I am looking forward to some of the answers.

Comment: You should really review previous questions on this subject. I found four possible duplicates (with some very good answers) in a few minutes: [The purpose of delegates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687626/the-purpose-of-delegates), [When would you use delegates in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191153/when-would-you-use-delegates-in-c), [Advantages of using delegates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302819/advantages-of-using-delegates), and [Are delegates not just shorthand interfaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95954/are-delegates-not-just-shorthand-interfaces).

Comment: As popular as this question is, it should be closed as a duplicate and merged with the other at least four duplicated questions.

Comment: I'd like to know who told the OP, "The delegate object can then be passed to code which can call the referenced method, without having to know at compile time which method will be invoked." Personally I hate `DynamicInvoke` (it is overused big time by a coworker).

Comment: @Jeff Sternal, @digEmAll, @0A0D: Agreed, actually. I didn't realize (though I should have suspected) what a blatant duplicate this was before posting my answer.

Comment: @Dan: No worries. I didn't either. Maybe it will enhance the search next time.

Comment: @Dan - no harm done. I agree with [Joel Coehoorn's remarks on meta about answering duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50358/) (and I'd better agree, since I did it myself!).

Comment: @Jeff Sternal You see that Joel Coehoorn's answer got a -1 on meta. There's a reason for that.

Comment: @George: until I read his post, I was against answering dupes too. For what it's worth, his answer has gone from -4 to -1 since I first saw it. And I must say, your epic back-and-forth with Jeff Atwood on this very topic was illuminating too - [Are Duplicates creating broken windows?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52530/are-duplicates-creating-broken-windows).

Comment: @Jeff Sternal the answers are great, and I hope they get merged; but the question title doesn't really add anything to the existing corpus of Delegates questions, and can be closed and its answers merged.

Comment: @George - absolutely agreed (as does Joel, by my reading of his answer).

Comment: Duplicated yes, but, much simpler and raises, and therefore answers so many questions several of my colleagues and I myself had on reading the other four "original" answers.

Answer (score 29):

Changing functionality at runtime is not what delegates accomplish.

Basically, delegates save you a crapload of typing.

For instance:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Age { get; }
    public double Height { get; }
    public double Weight { get; }
}

IEnumerable<Person> people = GetPeople();

var orderedByName = people.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
var orderedByAge = people.OrderBy(p => p.Age);
var orderedByHeight = people.OrderBy(p => p.Height);
var orderedByWeight = people.OrderBy(p => p.Weight);
```

In the above code, the `p => p.Name`, `p => p.Age`, etc. are all lambda expressions that evaluate to `Func<Person, T>` delegates (where `T` is `string`, `int`, `double`, and `double`, respectively).

Now let's consider how we could've achieved the above *without* delegates. Instead of having the `OrderBy` method take a delegate parameter, we would have to forsake genericity and define these methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> OrderByName(this IEnumerable<Person> people);
public static IEnumerable<Person> OrderByAge(this IEnumerable<Person> people);
public static IEnumerable<Person> OrderByHeight(this IEnumerable<Person> people);
public static IEnumerable<Person> OrderByWeight(this IEnumerable<Person> people);
```

This would **totally suck**. I mean, firstly, the code has become infinitely less reusable as it only applies to collections of the `Person` type. Additionally, we need to copy and paste the very same code four times, changing only 1 or 2 lines in each copy (where the relevant property of `Person` is referenced -- otherwise it would all look the same)! This would quickly become an unmaintainable mess.

So delegates allow you to make your code more reusable **and** more maintainable by abstracting away certain behaviors within code that can be switched in and out.

Comment: passing one function to another function as a parameter allows to pick what function to pass at runtime, which is "Changing functionality at runtime".

Comment: @alpav: Fair enough. I interpreted the phrase to mean basically assigning arbitrary functionality to existing classes that weren't designed to be modified, i.e., monkeypatching (as you can with, say, Ruby by re-opening classes or with JavaScript by assigning functions to arbitrary properties). My point was that you can't just change the implementation of any old class dynamically. But you're right that—if a class were *designed* to have customizable functionality based on delegates—then you would indeed be changing it at runtime.

Answer (score 20):

[.NET Delegates: A C# Bedtime Story](http://sellsbrothers.com/public/writing/delegates.htm)

Answer (score 12):

Delegates are extremely useful, especially after the introduction of linq and closures.

A good example is the 'Where' function, one of the standard linq methods. 'Where' takes a list and a filter, and returns a list of the items matching the filter. (The filter argument is a delegate which takes a T and returns a boolean.)

Because it uses a delegate to specify the filter, the Where function is extremely flexible. You don't need different Where functions to filter odd numbers and prime numbers, for example. The calling syntax is also very concise, which would not be the case if you used an interface or an abstract class.

More concretely, Where taking a delegate means you can write this:

```
var result = list.Where(x => x != null);
...
```

instead of this:

```
var result = new List<T>();
foreach (var e in list)
    if (e != null)
        result.add(e)
...
```

Answer (score 9):

> Why are delegates used if everytime I
>   declare a delegate, it needs a method
>   to point to? and if it needs a method
>   to point to, why not just call that
>   method directly?

Like interfaces, delegates let you decouple and generalize your code. You usually use delegates when you don't know in advance which methods you will want to execute - when you only know that you'll want to execute *something* that matches a certain signature.

For example, consider a timer class that will execute some method at regular intervals:

```
public delegate void SimpleAction();

public class Timer {
    public Timer(int secondsBetweenActions, SimpleAction simpleAction) {}
}
```

You can plug anything into that timer, so you can use it in any other project or applications without trying to predict how you'll use it and without limiting its use to a small handful of scenarios that you're thinking of *right now*.

Comment: Excellent example, but why not just add a method to the class that does the same thing?? Are delegates just to increase the elegance of the code? I get it, but yet I don't get it.

Answer (score 7):

Let me offer an example. If your class exposes an `event`, it can be assigned some number of delegates at runtime, which will be called to signal that something happened. When you wrote the class, you had no idea what delegates it would wind up running. Instead, this is determined by whoever uses your class.

Answer (score 3):

One example where a `delegate` is needed is when you have to modify a control in the UI thread and you are operating in a different thread. For example,

```
public delegate void UpdateTextBox(string data);

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    Invoke(new UpdateTextBox(textBoxData), data);
    ...

}

private void textBoxData(string data)
{
            textBox1.Text += data;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your example, once you've assigned a delegate to a variable, you can pass it around like any other variable. You can create a method accepting a delegate as a parameter, and it can invoke the delegate without needing to know where the method is really declared.

```
private int DoSomeOperation( Operations operation )
{
    return operation.Invoke(5,5);
}

...

MyClass f = new MyClass();
Operations p = new Operations(f.multiply);
int result = DoSomeOperation( p );
```

Delegates make methods into things that you can pass around in the same way as an int. You could say that variables don't give you anything extra because in

```
int i = 5;
Console.Write( i + 10 );
```

you see the value 5 being specified, so you might as well just say `Console.Write( 5 + 10 )`. It's true in that case, but it misses the benefits for being able to say

```
DateTime nextWeek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
```

instead of having to define a specifc `DateTime.AddSevenDays()` method, and an `AddSixDays` method, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

To give a concrete example, a particularly recent use of a delegate for me was `SendAsync()` on `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`.  I have an application that sends tons and tons of email and there was a noticeable performance hit waiting for the Exchange server to accept the message.  However, it was necessary to log the result of the interaction with that server.

So I wrote a delegate method to handle that logging and passed it to `SendAsync()` (we were previously just using `Send()`) when sending each email.  That way it can call back to the delegate to log the result and the application threads aren't waiting for the interaction to finish before continuing.

The same can be true of any external IO where you want the application to continue without waiting for the interaction to complete.  Proxy classes for web services, etc. take advantage of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegates to implement subscriptions and eventHandlers.
You can also (in a terrible way) use them to get around circular dependencies.

Or if you have a calculation engine and there are many possible calculations, then you can use a parameter delegate instead of many different function calls for your engine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(VS.80).aspx ?

Answer (score 1):

Using your example of `Operations`, imagine a calculator which has several buttons.
You could create a class for your button like this

```
class CalcButton extends Button {
   Operations myOp;
   public CalcButton(Operations op) {
      this.myOp=op; 
   }
   public void OnClick(Event e) {
      setA( this.myOp(getA(), getB()) ); // perform the operation
   }
}
```

and then when you create buttons, you could create each with a different operation

```
CalcButton addButton = new CalcButton(new Operations(f.multiply));
```

This is better for several reasons. You don't replicate the code in the buttons, they are generic. 
You could have multiple buttons that all have the same operation, for example on different panels or menus. You could change the operation associated with a button on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Delegates are used to solve an Access issue. When ever you want to have object foo that needs to call object bar's frob method but does not access to to frob method.

Object goo does have access to both foo and bar so it can tie it together using delegates. Typically bar and goo are often the same object.

For example a Button class typically doesn't have any access to the class defines a Button_click method.

So now that we have that we can use it for a whole lot things other than just events. Asynch patterns and Linq are two examples.

Answer (score 1):

It seems many of the answers have to do with inline delegates, which in my opinion are easier to make sense of than what I'll call "classic delegates."

Below is my example of how delegates allow a consuming class to change or augment behaviour (by effectively adding "hooks" so a consumer can do things before or after a critical action and/or prevent that behaviour altogether). Notice that all of the decision-making logic is provided from outside the `StringSaver` class. Now consider that there may be 4 different consumers of this class -- each of them can implement their own `Verification` and `Notification` logic, or none, as appropriate.

```
internal class StringSaver
{
    public void Save()
    {
        if(BeforeSave != null)
        {
            var shouldProceed = BeforeSave(thingsToSave);
            if(!shouldProceed) return;
        }
        BeforeSave(thingsToSave);

        // do the save

        if (AfterSave != null) AfterSave();
    }

    IList<string> thingsToSave;
    public void Add(string thing) { thingsToSave.Add(thing); }

    public Verification BeforeSave;
    public Notification AfterSave;
}

public delegate bool Verification(IEnumerable<string> thingsBeingSaved);
public delegate void Notification();

public class SomeUtility
{
    public void SaveSomeStrings(params string[] strings)
    {
        var saver = new StringSaver
            {
                BeforeSave = ValidateStrings, 
                AfterSave = ReportSuccess
            };

        foreach (var s in strings) saver.Add(s);

        saver.Save();
    }

    bool ValidateStrings(IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        return !strings.Any(s => s.Contains("RESTRICTED"));
    }

    void ReportSuccess()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Saved successfully");
    }
}
```

I guess the point is that the method to which the delegate points is not necessarily in the class exposing the delegate member.