# Showing error while using the Delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

Hello I have the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace myConsole
{
    public delegate int showDelegate();
   public class addmultipleClass
    {
        public  int addNumbers(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a + b);
        }
        public int multiplyNumbers(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a * b);
        }
    }
    class Delegate
    {      
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            addmultipleClass myObj = new addmultipleClass();
           showDelegate add = new showDelegate(myObj.addNumbers);
        }
    }

}
```

It is showing error like this `No overload for 'addNumbers' matches delegate  'myConsole.showDelegate'`

Why it is showing this error. Whats wrong in my code. Is it not correct way to reference the addNumbers() method.

Why should i use the delegate over here. I can achieve this by using class object. as `myObj.addNumbers(10,20);`
So what is the need for delegate?
Please help me.
Thank you all.

Comment: Modify showDelegate to match the parameters of addNumbers: `public delegate int showDelegate(int a, int b);` Delegates have to match  the number and type of parameters in addition to your return type.

Comment: why not make this an answer Jason? would surely vote for it - now every other answer will just be "borrowed" from your comment ;)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Jason. Post it as answer.... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify showDelegate to match the parameters of addNumbers:

```
public delegate int showDelegate(int a, int b);
```

Delegates have to match the number and type of parameters in addition to your return type.

The second part of your question is essentially asking: "why delegates?". For that answer, I suggest you look at other Stack Overflow posts for much more detailed and precise answers, for a start:

[Delegates, Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567478/delegates-why)
[when & why to use delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019402/when-why-to-use-delegates)
[The purpose of delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687626/the-purpose-of-delegates)

Comment: @Jason.. can you please look the question again